# how many bits should I expect to flip, if I flip each bit with probability 1/n?

Tags: runtime-analysis, probability-theory

I am trying to work out some analysis for an algorithm I am trying to write, one step of what I am doing require knowing the answer to the above question.

I know it might sound a bit simple, but I am not sure of the approach (formally using probability theory).

Assume I have an algorithm that loops over a bitstring (x1,x2,x3...xn).

- If my loop decides at each iteration flip x_i with probability 1/n. How many bits should I expect to flip at the end?
- or an alternative way to see this: If I decide I want to flip k bits in my string and sample u.a.r the number the k integers between [1 and n]  . what is the probability for a single bit X_i to be flipped?

Can someone please answer these and/(or preferably) explain the reasoning to answer such questions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X_i$ be a random variable that equals $1$ if your algorithm flips the $i$-th bit and $0$ otherwise. Let $X = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ be the random variable counting the number of flipped bits.
Your first question asks about $\mathbb{E}[X]$.

The expected value of a random variable is a linear function, therefore:
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[X] &= \mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right] = \sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb{E}\left[ X_i\right] = \sum_{i=1}^n \left(0 \cdot \Pr(X_i=0) + 1 \cdot \Pr(X_i=1)\right) \\&= \sum_{i=1}^n \Pr(X_i=1) = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n} = 1.
\end{align*}
$$

Regarding the second question, since you say that you want to flip $k$ bits, I assume that you are sampling $k \le n$ elements from $\{1, \dots, n\}$ u.a.r. and *without replacement*. In that case the probability of flipping each bit is exactly $\frac{k}{n}$.

If you instead sample *with replacement*, fix some index $i$ and look at the probability of the event $E_j$ = "the $j$-th sample is *not* $i$". The probability of $E_j$ is $\frac{n-1}{n}=1-\frac{1}{n}$. Since the $E_j$s are independent, the probability of *not* sampling $i$ is the product of the probabilities of $E_1, \dots, E_k$, i.e.:
$$
\Pr\left(\bigcap_{j=1}^k E_j \right) = \prod_{j=1}^k \Pr(E_j) = \left( 1-\frac{1}{n} \right)^k.
$$

Since you are interested in the complementary event, its probability is $1-\left( 1-\frac{1}{n} \right)^k$.

Comment: Note that $1-\left( 1-\frac{1}{n} \right)^k$ is the probability of a given bit being chosen *at least once* in the sampling-with-replacement case. Depending on the situation, it may be more important to know the probability of a given bit being chosen *an odd number of times* (since flipping a bit an *even* number of times is equivalent to not flipping it at all), which is significantly more complicated.

Comment: @ruakh: the problem statement is unclear, but it seems that OP loops only once.

Comment: @ruakh. Good point. In that case the probability of flipping a fixed bit an odd number of times is $\sum_{i=1}^{\lceil k/2 \rceil} \binom{k}{2i-1} (\frac{1}{n})^{2i-1} (1-\frac{1}{n})^{k-2i+1} = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2}(1-\frac{2}{n})^k$. See also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82841/probability-that-a-n-frac12-binomial-random-variable-is-even).